# Allow only certain user type to create account

Tags: 7, users

I have to add new role, for users than can create accounts for others.

I create new role and add create profile content permission.

But when I am anonymous link 'clear new account' still appear and I can create account. I want only certain role to create account, not everyone.

Could somebody give me any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable account creation by anonymous:
At admin/user/settings check "Only site administrators can create new user accounts"

Allow the account-creator role to administer users:
At admin/user/permissions -> user module -> administer users

Use a module such a [Protect Critical Users](http://drupal.org/project/protect_critical_users) if the account-creator role should not be able to touch the superuser (user1).

Comment: a stray colon has attached itself to your module link

Comment: ha! it's removed

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, under *Admin*, *Configuration*, *Account settings* (/admin/config/people/accounts), there is an option called *Who can register accounts?*, there you have to select *Administrators only*.